# Using Image with Brand

Tags: java, gwt, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a Image with my GWT Bootstrap application. I replaced the  widget with  widget however the `ResponsiveNavBar` height is resized when using GWT Image widget compared to using the Brand widget.

```
    <ui:with field='res' type='com.mycomp.mygwt.client.Resources'/>

    <b:ResponsiveNavbar position="TOP" scrollspy="false"> <!--  inverse="true" -->
        <!-- <b:Brand href="#">MyApp</b:Brand> -->
        <g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/>
    </b:ResponsiveNavbar>
```

- Is there any way to assign a Image to Brand using ui:with resource?
- Also, why in the GWT-Bootstrap showcase, the `ResponsiveNavBar` field `inverse="true"` is set, but when I use it in my application I get this error:

  ```
  [ERROR] [MyGWT] - Class ResponsiveNavbar has no appropriate setInverse() method Element <b:ResponsiveNavbar inverse='true' position='TOP' scrollspy='false'> (:11)
  ```

I'm using GWT-Bootstrap version: `2.0.4.0-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for your questions:

> -Is there any way to assign a Image to Brand using ui:with resource?

I think not. I believe that you can do something like:

```
<b:Brand href="#"><g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/></b:Brand>
```

If it doesnt work, just create a link with the css class "brand", and put your image in it.

> Also, why in the GWT-Bootstrap showcase, the ResponsiveNavBar field inverse="true" is set, but when I use it in my application I get this error:

GWT-Bootstrap 2.0.4.0 is based on bootstrap 2.0.4, so, it doesn't have this property. Try GWT-Bootstrap 2.1.*.

Hope it helps.